# Fetch some data from a webpage

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I have used [this tutorial to fetch all the content of some webpage via c# code](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3A_What_is_the_easiest_way_to_fetch_a_Web_page_in_.NET).

I now want to gather into an IEnumerable collection all the strings which are decorated in the following text pattern: (i.e. MY-TEXT)

```
data-address=" MY-TEXT "></
```

How can I do that?
I tried using "string.split()" but got to many "white noises".

Any idea?

Comment: What webpage is that? Is it HTML (which doesn't have any `data-address` attribute AFAIK)? Or XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution is to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and let it handle the parsing/scraping for you. Here is an example:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@data-address]");

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["data-address"].Value);
}
```

This will fetch stackoverflow.com, find all elements which has a `data-address` attribute and then print the value of that attribute.

Comment: few questions:1) I got the following error:"Expression must evaluate to a node-set". What went wrong? 2)how did you get to this opensource dll? just for me to know for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is well formed I'd load the content into an XDocument and query over it with LINQ to XML.

Comment: You (probably) can't load HTML into an `XDocument`, event if it is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

@alexn is right. A small correction though:

```
  var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@data-address]");
```

added the *